# How to clean a large image dataset for deep learning purposes?

Tags: python, deep-learning, dataset, data-cleaning

I have a large image dataset with 477 classes (about 500,000 images). Each class contains some irrelevant images, so when it's trained on a model the model accuracy is not acceptable. Regarding the number of classes, it takes much time to clean the dataset manually with help of a human. Is there any way to remove such images automatically? (like a machine learning method or algorithm)

Comment: You can expect machine to do it unless you train it properly, so u have to do it manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that for now the best (most reliable) way to clean image datasets is manually. There might be some techniques that could be applied. For now, services like Azure and Amazon ML have some ways to clean data, however, I don't know if they apply that to images (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/team-data-science-process/prepare-data). For sure there are companies that have a well developed way of doing this.
Maybe you can get inspired by this paper: https://stefan.winklerbros.net/Publications/icip2014a.pdf

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is using a classifier to remove unwanted images from your dataset but this way is useful only for huge datasets and it is not as reliable as the normal way (manual cleansing). For example, an [SVM classifier](https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/multiclass-svms-1.html) can be trained to extract images from each class. More details will be added after testing this method.